# Oracle 11g manual user authentication

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need help to create a manual user authentication in Oracle DB 11g.

A separate table is there which contains authorized user names. If the user is not in the table, he will get disconnected with a message stating something like 'you are not authorized' or something.

This the function I created to get return code based on username presence in ref table:

```
create or replace function user_check return integer is
 user_name varchar2(10);
 cursor usr is select * from user_ref;
begin
 select USERNAME into user_name 
   from v$session where audsid = sys_context('userenv','sessionid');
 for u in usr loop
   if u.user_name = user_name then
     return 1;
     goto out_of_loop;
   end if;
 end loop;
 return 0;
 <<out_of_loop>>
 null;
end;
/
```

I am trying to create a trigger as:

```
create or replace trigger user_verify_trg after logon on database
declare
  sid varchar2(10);
  serial varchar2(10);
  q varchar2(100);
begin
  if(gs.user_check = 1) then
    select SID, serial# into sid,serial 
    from v$session where audsid = sys_context('userenv','sessionid');
    q := 'alter system kill session '||sid||','||serial;
    execute immediate q;
  end if;
end;
/
```

But it's not working. Please help.

Comment: Err ... what's the rational behind this kind of user management scheme ? What's wrong with the [normal database users](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/users.htm#DBSEG002) ?

Comment: Default user access allows all the users from different teams to connect and we can't restrict the user permissions. After deployment, we need the access to be restricted to the live team only, for whom the usernames will be provided in the table user_ref.

Comment: I'm sorry but to me that argument sounds just silly. What prevents you to change the permissions after deployment so that only the live team can access the database ?

Comment: Yea ... I also told them to do change in create session permission, but that is what they told me to implement. Can you please give it a try.